# keep throwing error : win chill index as 0

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, functional-programming

I keep on running the code and it always shows the win chill index as 0 how do i fix this? my code is

```
// include necessary libraries
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
//prototype
double WC(double T, double v, double wc);

double WC(double T, double v, double wc)
// if statement for wind speed great than 4.8
{
    if (v > 4.8)
        wc = 13.12 + 0.6215* T - 11.37 * pow(v, 0.16) + 0.3965 * T * pow(v, 0.16);
    else wc = T;
        return wc;
}

// prototype 
void categories(double wc);

// function categories
void categories(double wc)
{
    //output
    cout << "Wind chill index is: " << wc << " degrees Celsius" << endl;
    //if-else statements for index
    if (wc <= 0 && wc > -25)
        cout << "This level of wind chill will cause discomfort." << endl;
    else if (wc <= -25 && wc > -45)
        cout << "This level of wind chill can have risk of skin freezing(frostbite)." << endl;
    else if (wc <= -45 && wc > -60)
        cout << "This level of wind chill will cause exposed skin to freeze within minutes" << endl;
    else if (wc <= -60)
        cout << "his level of wind chill will cause exposed skin to freeze in under 2 minutes" << endl;
    return;
}

//main function 
int main()
{
    double T;
    double v;
    double wc = 0;

    //prompt user for input
    cout << "Enter the current wind speed and temperature: " << endl;
    cin >> v >> T;
    //calling the functions
    WC(T, v, wc);
    categories(wc);

    return 0;

}
```

i think it might be because i declare it as wc=0 in my main function but earlier in the code i have an equation that set a wc value why isnt that being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change

```
double WC(double T, double v, double wc);
```

to

```
double WC(double& T, double& v, double& wc);
```

OR

```
WC(T, v, wc);
```

to

```
wc = WC(T, v, wc);
```

Comment: but if i add the & the program returns the wc correctly but doesnt out the other line "this level of wind chill will cause discomfort"

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because in C you should use the return value like this

`wc=WC(T,v,wc)`

If you look at your code, you have declared the return value as double, so use it

Answer (score 0):

wc is "**passed by value**" to the function WC(). Hence, in that function the wc will a local variable and the same will not to reflected to the wc in your main. Since you are returning the value of wc, you can do this way :

wc = WC();

However, in you first case wherein if (v > 4.8), you will have to return wc.

An alternative method would be to "**pass by reference**".